# Very intermittent WinRM Failure

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have a bit of a stumper that I'm hoping someone can make suggestions on fixing or tracing the root cause.

I am using the powershell command Stop-Service on a remote machine, which works without issue 99.9% of the time. That being said, I have a process that runs weekly to restart a specific service that keeps erroring out throwing the following error:

> WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the  specified
>   computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
>   network, and that a firewall exception for  the WinRM service is
>   enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
>   firewall exception for public  profiles limits access to remote
>   computers within the same local subnet

I had a look at the CPU usage, Mem usage, Thread count, page file usage, and network traffic and they all are low.

If the task is run again immediately after, it succeeds without issue. This happens nearly every week.

Anyone have ideas on where to look for a root cause?

Comment: I would run a network capture on the remote server to determine whether or not the traffic is hitting the box when the remote command fails.

Comment: I wasn't running a network capture but I do have monitoring up on connections to the machine and there were none during the time. It seems like the call dropped in transport (or failed to reach the machine) but I have no idea where the failure is happening.

Comment: This advice exceeds SO a bit (try at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or [NetworkEngineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) for more info) but identify the route the traffic takes from the server the call fails from, then see if you can find that traffic and where it stops on the networking equipment. If you aren't in a networking role, you'll need a network admin to assist you here.

Comment: How are you issuing the Stop-Service command to run it on a remote machine?  For example, are you using pssession, invoke-command, or a DevOps task to perform the Stop-Service command?